# Unable to add bold or italic text

Tags: html, css

Ok so Here is some sample code I have:

```
<div id="Noah">
    <font face="Times New Roman" size="2">
        <b>John Miceahl</b><br />
        Cool guy, over all cool guy<br />
        youtube.com/JohnMiceahl
    </font>
</div>
```

Even though I have the `<b>` tags in place, it is not showing up in bold! I'm sure there is a quick fix to this and I am doing something slightly wrong.

EDIT: ADDED LINK TO CSS CODE:

http://pastebin.com/3UzA8hUA

Comment: Use `<strong>` instead

Comment: HTML style really deprecated, read more about CSS

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k71cxvo1/)!

Comment: There is issue somewhere else in your html or css. If you simply copy your lines and make a new html page and view that in a browser that will work fine and show up in bold. So try finding out the issue, may be in your css where you must have added `b{ font-weight:normal;}` or something like that.

Comment: You should include the *relevant* CSS (preferably, minimal CSS that still reproduces the issue) in the question itself, instead of expecting others to debug some bulky style sheet for you.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Sorry buddy, I'll make sure to do that next time!

Comment: And the CSS code linked to does *not* reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I don't feel like arguing right now, the problem is already fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just learn how to do it in non deprecated and way easier ways:

In your particular case, try this HTML

```
<div class="name_tag"><span>John Miceahl</span> 
    <p>Cool guy, over all cool guy</p>
    <p>youtube.com/JohnMiceahl</p>
</div>
```

And then this CSS

```
.name_tag {
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
.name_tag span {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Now you can re-use `.name_tag` as many times as you want, and you can change span for a heading, like `h3` or `h4`. Clean, easy and works 100 out of 100 times.

But again, try to learn some HTML5, at least the basics, you'll need it if you want to build web pages

[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywewrrdk/)

Comment: Yea, some of my HTML methods might be a little old (need to study up on it!) Also wondering, instead of using class can I just use div id? Since those IDs are alse being used in jQuery/JS.

Comment: I added the class to make it re-usable, but you can have both, like `<div id="John" class="name_tag">`. Now you can target the ID while re-using your CSS without having to re-declare it every time

Comment: This does not address the question why the original code does not work. (And it does; the problem is outside that code, possibly in the use of a CSS reset, and using different markup just casually hides the symptoms.)

Comment: @Fabio looks like after I do that the name becomes bold, but does not become Times New Roman. I'll paste in the CSS file I have in the post.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela : by now I'm aware that you're against things that work and prefer forms over performance. But in this specific case, please show where is the question, because I don't see any. I see a title "Unable to add bold or italic text" and " I am doing something slightly wrong". Instead of taking him down the path of "OK, keep doing it wrong" I prefer to tell him how to do it right, sorry if it bothers you

Comment: @user3890432 , the CSS is fine, are you using exactly the same HTML? It sounds like you have some unclosed tag

Comment: Yea, for now I'm using my previous code but added the class and the code to the CSS file (So my problem is now fixed!). I'm going to read up some more about HTML5,CSS later too (:

Comment: @Fabio, if you read the apparent intent and not the form, the question is apparently why the `b` element does not appear in bold. Your answer does not address that at all.